# Trying to search on the last 4 of SSN (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have found multiple resources that let me know how to retrieve the last 4 of a SSN.  But I am trying to search the database for matches of the last 4 that I am provided. I am working with Oracle btw.  I've tried a few different things but below is basically what I mean:

```
SELECT gm.plan_name, tpam.third_prty_admin_name, pm.partcpnt_first_name,
                           pm.partcpnt_last_name, pm.partcpnt_id, gm.grp_id,
                           tpam.third_prty_admin_id,
                           pm.partcpnt_birth_dt,pm.partcpnt_setup_dt
                      FROM gva_s01.partcpnt_mstr pm,
                           gva_s01.grp_mstr gm,
                           gva_s01.third_prty_admin_mstr tpam
                     WHERE gm.cntrct_id = 'CNTRCTID0000'
                       AND gm.third_prty_admin_id = 0
                       AND gm.third_prty_admin_id = tpam.third_prty_admin_id
                       AND gm.cntrct_id = pm.cntrct_id
                       --This is where I can't figure it out
                       AND SUBSTRING(pm.partcpnt_id, -4) = '1234'
```

Comment: If you are working with Oracle, you should add it too as a tag to your question

Comment: What can't you figure out?

Comment: `pm.partcpnt_id LIKE '%1234'` would do the trick. But so would your substring. What problem are you having?

Comment: SQL99 syntax would be `SUBSTRING(pm.partcpnt_id FROM -4) = '1234'`

Comment: @mvp: No, a negative FROM will not start backwards, this would *start at character -4 up to the end of the string", simply returning the full string.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you want [`SUBSTR( string, position )`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679) and a negative position will count from the end of the string. So:

```
AND SUBSTR(pm.partcpnt_id, -4) = '1234'
```

Or you can use `LIKE`:

```
AND pm.partcpnt_id LIKE '%1234'
```